# kubernetes : Unable to reach out my container via ClusterIp service, connection refused

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am running tests to understand ClusterIp service.
I have created 1 nginx pod and 1 service to expose nginx container as described below.

## create an nginx pod

```
kubectl run  nginx --image nginx --restart Never
```

## create a clusterip svc

```
kubectl expose pod nginx --name nginxsvc --port 80 --target-port 8080
```

## check the svc creation

```
kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   35m     <none>
nginxsvc     ClusterIP   10.106.33.237   <none>        80/TCP    8m47s   run=nginx
```

## check the pod creation

```
kubectl get po -o wide
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx   1/1     Running   0          10m   10.244.1.6   node01   <none>           <none>
```

## Now if i try to reach the container in pod nginx directly

```
curl 10.244.1.6:80
```

## ==> It works and i have nginx page displayed.

#Now if i try to reach the container in pod nginx via ClusterIp from node01

```
curl 10.106.33.237:80

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.106.33.237 port 80: Connection refused
```

Clusterip service is supposed to be the way to connect inside a cluster.

I have also run the test with Nodeport service and i am having the same issue.

Can someone help me here ? What i have missed ?

Thanks,

Why am i not able to reach the container from clusterIp here ?

Answer (score 0):

[ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) is a service whose IP is only accessible  *within* the cluster, hence the name, and hence the reason you can access it within the nginx pod. You can't use this IP outside of the cluster.

From the documentation:

> `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default `ServiceType`.

If you want to access the service outside of the cluster, you need an external IP. This is a "LoadBalancer" service instead. This will provision a loadbalancer from the underlying provider (if you're running Kubernetes on a cloud provider like Amazon, Google, or Azure, this will provision the corresponding load balancer service for them).